# How to use previous used cookies when relaunching the application using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new to cookies related thing in android. 
In my application i have used retrofit for API call. In API they are using cookie authentication. 
When i launch the application for the first time, it is working fine. But after i remove the application background and then relaunches the application, I am getting 401, UnAuthorized error response.

My normal application flow is 
 1. Install the application
 2. Login in using API
 3. For successful API response, launches the Home screen 
For the second launching, the application is directly goes to home screen.

This is my Application class onCreate Function,

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
    SetCookieCache cookieCache = new SetCookieCache();
    ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(cookieCache, new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this));
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build();

    if (mRetrofit == null) {
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your cookie persistent? I believe that `PersistentCookieJar` saves only the persistent ones.

Comment: You can use an interceptor to set cookie when the request is made. and save your cookies in sharedPrefrences

Comment: @user1779222 Thank you so much, you saved me. As you said it was filtering it. I removed the filtration and it worked.